# ALTER TABLE failed because one or more objects access this column. after running NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE RoomReservation NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL

ALTER TABLE RoomReservation ALTER COLUMN HotelNumber INTEGER NOT NULL
```

I thought removing the contraint would allow me to make some necessary changes, but I was wrong.

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The object 'DF_RoomReservation_HotelNumber' is dependent on column 'HotelNumber'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 5
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN HotelNumber failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Is there a way to make this work. I am not sure why removing all constraint on a table wouldn't allow me to run an alter table query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just guessing by looking at the name, `'DF_RoomReservation_HotelNumber'` is probably a `DEFAULT` constraint, not a `CHECK` constraint. So try this statement first.

```
ALTER TABLE RoomReservation DROP CONSTRAINT DF_RoomReservation_HotelNumber
```

Comment: How do we revert it? The issue is that I don't want to break the database.

Comment: You script out all the constraints that reference the column so you can recreate them after altering the column.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: From SSMS right-click the constraint and select `Script Constraint as` then choose `DROP and CREATE To` - here it is optional which you choose; I usually choose `New Query Editor Window` for the first one, and `Clipboard` for any subsequent ones. Now you can insert your `ALTER` statement between the `DROP` and `CREATE` statements.